# Good way to tokenize a string to store values? Or alternative for user input

Tags: c++

Hello again Stackoverflow, I'm here again asking a question for my C++ programming class. The problem I am facing is mostly to due with user input from the keyboard. I need to be able to take the user input to decide what function to call and what arguments to give the function. For example something like `add 5` would call the add function with the argument 5. At first I tried overloading the >> operator to take both a string and an int but the problem I ran into was the program was unable to take input without the int such as `deletemax` so I had to throw that idea out. So now I am back to tokenizing the input but we are not allowed to use Boost for this program so I came up with something like this using sstream

```
    bool out = false;
string token;
string In;
int num;

do
{
    cout << "heap> ";
    cin >> In;
    istringstream iss(In);
    while(getline(iss, token, ' '))
    {
      cout << token << endl; //I know this is incorrect but just not what to replace it with
    }
    out = ProcessCommand (token, num); //Takes string and int to call correct functions
} while (out != true);
```

The problem lies in that I'm not quite sure how to correctly tokenize the string so I can get 2 string and convert the second string to an int. Can anyone offer me some assistance? I would greatly appreciate it. Also if there is a better way to go about this than I am trying I would also like to hear it.

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: The easy way out would be to use [boost tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html), but maybe that would defeat the purpose of the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Googling "C++ string tokenize" will get you plenty of hits, with the first hit being on Stackoverflow. But you should take a stab at it. I'm guessing it's the point of the exercise.

You said "argumentS", which suggests that commands you support take varying numbers of arguments. I'd break it down like this:

1. read a line from the user
2. split line into 'tokens' on space boundaries, store tokens in a list
3. based on the first token in the list, choose a command to execute
4. pass the list of tokens to the command, so it can validate/interpret them as arguments

The tricky part is #2. Do you know about container classes yet? You can use `vector<string>` to store the chunks you parse. To do the actual parsing, you iterate through the characters of the string. Skip whitespace until you find a non-whitespace character (or run out of characters). Save this position: `start`. Then skip non-whitespace until you find whitespace (or run out of characters). Save this position: `end`. Copy the substring represented between from `start` to `end` and copy that to your token list.

Working out the actual details of this, making sure you don't have off-by-on-errors, etc. is going to be challenging if you've never done it before, which I'm guessing is the point.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to read in the whole of user input all at once.

For example you could read in the first bit of user input (the operation, `add` or `deletemax`, etc). From there depending on the operation you could continue to read arguments from input (in the case of `add`) or begin performing the operation immediately (in the case of `deletemax`).

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to have a `std::map` of function names as keys and required number of arguments as values. You'd read a line of input, get the function name and then decide whether you need aditional arguments. I'd write a function that'd return a `vector` of arguments extracted from a string stream or an empty vector in case the input was invalid.